# Vagrant box with TCP port range around 49700 LISTENTING?

Tags: tcp, vagrant, port

I'm running a precise64 box on vagrant. On a a few boxes, I see port range near 49728-75 and a similar  listening. Is this a vm thing?

What is this port?